# On Click of radio button navigate to new JSP

Tags: java, jsp

This is my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>Select Payment Method<BR><BR>
<font size=""><marquee behavior="alternate">PAYMENT GATEWAY</marquee></font>
<form action="S2ShowPay.jsp" method="post">
        <input type="radio" value="NET BANKING" name="payment" >NET BANKING<br><br>
        <input type="radio" value="DEBIT CARD PAYMENT" name="payment">DEBIT CARD<BR><br>
        <input type="radio" value="CASH ON DELIVERY" name="payment" >CASH ON DELIVERY<br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="NEXT"/>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to navigate to netbanking.jsp when I click on Net Banking radio button and Debit.jsp repectively, using only jsp and some javascript.

Please help.

Comment: Can you use servlets? If not, why?

Comment: How do I use servlets?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what's your expected result, Perhaps you can try this. Correct me if im wrong.

### Using location.href

```
function fnPayment()
{
    if(document.getElementById("a").checked ==true || document.getElementById("b").checked ==true)

    {
        location.href = "http://www.google.com"; //your jsp file
    }
}
</script>

    <input type="radio" value="NET BANKING" name="payment" id="a">NET BANKING<br><br>
    <input type="radio" value="DEBIT CARD PAYMENT" name="payment" id="b">DEBIT CARD<BR><br>
    <input type="radio" value="CASH ON DELIVERY" name="payment" id="c">CASH ON DELIVERY<br><br>
```

### Using response redirect

Since you have created `S2ShowPay.jsp`, you can pass parameter to it once you clicked next button and put response redirect based on the parameter.

```
    <input type="radio" value="NET" name="payment" >NET BANKING<br><br>
    <input type="radio" value="DEBIT" name="payment">DEBIT CARD<BR><br>
    <input type="radio" value="CASH" name="payment" >CASH ON DELIVERY<br><br>
```

S2ShowPay.jsp

```
String payment_ind = request.getParameter("payment");

if(payment_ind.equals("NET") || payment_ind.equals("DEBIT") )
{
   response.sendRedirect("netbanking.jsp"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code within `head` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirectPage(use,rname){
for (var val = 0, r1=use.elements; val < r1.length; val++)
if(r1[val].name==rname&&r1[val].checked)
use.action=r1[val].value;
}
</script>
```

Change your `form` tag like this:

```
<div>
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="redirectPage(this, 'r1');">
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="netbanking.jsp">NET BANKING<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="Debit.jsp">DEBIT CARD<BR><br>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="cashondelivery.jsp">CASH ON DELIVERY<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Next"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Select the desired `radio` button and then clicking `Next` button will redirect to respective page.